# Incorporate Pandas Data Frame in Query to Database

Tags: python, sql, pandas, odbc

I'm trying to figure out how to treat a pandas data frame as a SQL table when querying a database in Python.

I'm coming from a SAS background where work tables can easily be incorporated into direct database queries.

For example:

```
Select a.first_col, 
       b.second_col
from database.table1 a
left join work.table1 b on a.id = b.id;
```

Here work.table1 is not in the database, but is a dataset held in the local SAS server.

In my research I have found ways to write a data frame to a database and then include that in the query.  I do not have write access to the database, so that is not an option for me.

I also know that I can use `sqlalchemy` with `pd.to_sql()` to put a data frame into a SQL engine, but I can't figure out if there is a way to connect that engine with the `pyodbc` connection I have with the database.

I also tried this though I didn't think it would work (names of tables and columns altered).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([A342,B432,W345],columns=['id'])

query = '''
select a.id, b.id
from df a 
left join database.base_table b on a.id= b.id
'''
 
query_results = pd.read_sql_query(query,connection)
```

As I expected it didn't work.

I'm connecting to a Netezza database, I'm not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, it would have to be written to its own table in order to be queried, although I'm not familiar with Netezza.

Why not perform the join (in pandas a "merge") purely in pandas? Understand if the sql table is massive this isn't feasible but,

```
query = """
        SELECT id, x
        FROM a
        """

a = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

df = # some dataframe in memory

pd.merge(df, a, on='id', how='left')
```

see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html for good docs about sql and pandas similarities

Comment: I can't pull the query into a dataframe and then use pd.merge because it would be too large.  I'm wanting to use a much smaller dataframe as the base table and then use a left join to only query the records I need. To query the Netezza table without a filter (which is how I would need to do it to get every potential record) isn't feasible.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: how small? can you fit the super small dataframe into a query and join with that?